# How can I enable HP DM3 Wifi?

Tags: wireless

I have a HP DM3 Wifi. I am unable to turn on the Wifi. It says "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch". I have pressed the hardware switch many times, but it's not turning on. Its **red**. I bought a new USB by Netis which works fine on Windows, but am unable to get it working on Ubuntu. I have tried the following command:

```
rfkill list all
```

In my networks, it shows both cards but says it is disabled by hardware switch. Is there any way to forcefully enable it ?

Following are the models:

1. HP DM3 1039M
2. Netis WF-2110 Wireless-N Mini USB Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `rfkill unblock all`, the other command you've tried only lists devices, but doesn't unblock them.

Comment: worked like a charm